# JavaScript - Create some CSS classes that can be used to give alternate styling to the table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do this with JavaScript:

- Create some CSS classes that can be used to give alternate styling to the table rows.
- Write JavaScript that will find all the table rows inside the table body and then give 
  those alternate styles, that you created in the CSS file, to the odd and even rows.

This is what I have - How would I do this With JavaScript? Only JavaScript, not jQuery.

Thanks So much for the Help you can close this thread :)

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/dom-scripting/striped-tables.shtml).

Comment: just use css pseudo classes `:odd` and `:even`

Comment: @keune: those are not CSS pseudo-classes, you may be thinking of [`:nth-child(odd)`/`:nth-child(even)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (var i = 0; i<trs.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2)
        trs[i].className += 'new_class';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VvQ7D/1/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use javascript? this can be done by just using css:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) > td{
background-color:red;
}
tr:nth-child(even) > td{
background-color:green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KgXLk/